# Do you know what problem I have with my spring security config?

Tags: java, spring, api, security, authentication

I need to authenticate all requests starting from "/api/auth" except "/api/auth/login" and "/api/auth/token/refresh". This is my security config configure method. Problem is, it does not work as intended. It checks for authentication for "/api/auth/token/refresh" even though I assigned permitAll to it.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/api/auth/login").antMatcher("/api/auth/token/refresh")
                .antMatcher("/api/auth/**")
                .antMatcher("/api/**");
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST)
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/login","/api/auth/token/refresh").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first 3 lines of code.

Javadoc of [`antMatcher(String)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#antMatcher-java.lang.String-) says:

> Invoking `antMatcher(String)` will **override** previous invocations of [...], `antMatcher(String)`, [...].

Calling it 4 times doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It wasn't there previously. I found it somewhere and added. It wasn't working before and it is not working now